# Como criar um filtro com imagens?

Tags: html, jquery, css, json, filtro

Estou criando um projeto que lista diversas imagens de estabelecimentos, quero criar um filtro para que eu pesquise o nome da loja e apareça apenas ela, ou pesquisar o tipo de culinária, distancia e tudo mais.

Tentei utilizar um jquery mais não funcionou se alguém souber um jeito melhor e puder ajudar eu agradeço.

```css
#inicio {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../img/fundo.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 100%; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1{
 font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black;

}
h6{
 font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
 color: #ff0000;
  

}

img.image{
 width:320px;
  height:220px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.msg{
 margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s ease;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 21px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 21px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999999;
  margin-top: -36px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  

}

.image {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 15px;
 bottom: 0;
}

.msg:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    
 <title>Desafio - Pablo Valle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" id="inicio">
  <h1>Desafio Gourmet</h1>
  <h6> Mensagem secundaria não sei o que colocar</h6><br>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="busca" placeholder="Nome do estabelecimento"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row text-center " id="filtro">
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/1.jpg"> <div class="overlay" >Alma Chef - Contemporânea 7KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Akemi - Japonesa 10KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >68 La Pizzeria Lourdes - Pizzaria 5KM</div></div>
  
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/4.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Birosca S2 - Contemporânea 5KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/5.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Café com Letras - Contemporânea 2KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/6.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Duke'n'Duke - Hamburguearia 7KM</div></div>
  
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/7.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Duke'n'Duke - Hamburguearia 5KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/8.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Campagne - Brasileira 2KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/9.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Albanos Lourdes - Brasileira 4KM</div></div>
  
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/10.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Benvindo - Contemporânea 10KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/11.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Marilia - Pizzaria 7KM</div></div>
  <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="img/portfolio/12.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Marukame - Japonesa 5KM</div></div>
  
  </div>
  
  
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#busca").keyup(function(){
        var texto = $(this).val();
         
        $("#filtro img").css("display", "block");
        $("#filtro img").each(function(){
            if($(this).text().indexOf(texto) < 0)
               $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});
</script>
      </body>
   
   
</html>
```

Comment: Cara vc quer um filtro dinâmico ou estático? Vc pode incluir na tag pai da sua imagem `div class="msg"` alguns custom atributes como `data-km="10km"` ou `data-km="20km"` e `data-culinaria="japonesa"` ou `data-culinaria="italiana"` e depois até mesmo com CSS vc pega esses custom datas e filtra apena o que vc quer usando um radio button escondido por exemplo... Isso é só uma ideia para te dar uma luz, mas existem outras formas de fazer

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser pode fazer o filtro pelo texto da `div` segue o exemplo com código explicado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#busca").keyup(function() {
    var texto = $(this).val();              // pega o texto do input
         
    if(texto.length > 5) {                  // se o texto for maior que 5
      $(".msg").each(function() {           // faz um for em todas as divs
        var valor = $(this).text();         // pega o texto de cada div
           
        if(!valor.includes(texto)) {        // a div que não conter o texto do input
          $(this).css("display", "none");   // não apareceram só a div com o texto
        }
      })
              
    } else if(texto.length == 0) {          // se o input tiver vazio
      $(".msg").css("display", "block");    // mostra todas as divs
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#inicio {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("../img/fundo.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 100%; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1{
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black;
}
h6{
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  color: #ff0000;
}

img.image{
  width:320px;
  height:220px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.msg{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s ease;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 21px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 21px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999999;
  margin-top: -36px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  

}

.image {
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
bottom: 0;
}
.msg:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" id="inicio">
   <h1>Desafio Gourmet</h1>
   <h6> Mensagem secundaria não sei o que colocar</h6><br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="busca" placeholder="Nome do estabelecimento"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
   
<div class="container">
   <div class="row text-center " id="filtro">
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg"> <div class="overlay" >Alma Chef - Contemporânea 7KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Akemi - Japonesa 10KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >68 La Pizzeria Lourdes - Pizzaria 5KM</div></div>
  
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Birosca S2 - Contemporânea 5KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Café com Letras - Contemporânea 2KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Duke'n'Duke - Hamburguearia 7KM</div></div>
  
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Duke'n'Duke - Hamburguearia 5KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Campagne - Brasileira 2KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Albanos Lourdes - Brasileira 4KM</div></div>
  
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Benvindo - Contemporânea 10KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Marilia - Pizzaria 7KM</div></div>
      <div class="msg"><img class="image" src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" > <div class="overlay" >Marukame - Japonesa 5KM</div></div>
  
   </div>     
  
</div>
```